# MemoryError: Unable to allocate 797. MiB for an array with shape (51, 51, 40169) and data type float64

Tags: python, machine-learning, statsmodels

```
sarima_preds = []
history = [x for x in train_series]

for t in range(len(test_series)):
model = SARIMAX(history, order=(1,1,1), seasonal_order=(1,1,1,24), enforce_stationarity=False, enfore_invertibility=False)
model_fit = model.fit()
output = model_fit.forecast()
sarima_preds.append(output[0])
history.append(test_series[t])

sarima_pred_series = pd.Series(sarima_preds, index=test_series.index)


MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File statsmodels\tsa\statespace\_kalman_smoother.pyx:1014, in statsmodels.tsa.statespace._kalman_smoother.dKalmanSmoother.allocate_arrays()
```

I'm getting memory error after it runs for approximately 1-2 hours. I'm unable to understand what shall I do next. I tried searching for sources and I'm unable to get any one of them.

Comment: How much memory does your machine have available? Are you using a 64bit version of Python?

Comment: what does `import sys;print("%x" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)` give you?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga After running the above code in Jyupter I'm getting " 7fffffffffffffff True "

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm using 64 bit python and the memory size is 16 GB(RAM) and 512 GB (SSD).

Comment: Do you understand what the code is doing? Do you understand why it wants to create an array of this size? Does it make sense that it would try to make an array this big? Did you try to check how much memory the program is using, while it runs? Do you understand why the array would take that much memory?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel if you can explain me what the code is doing? That would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You could try either pre-allocating the memory instead of appending to lists or threshold which results are saved if you don't care about having each one. To pre-allocate...

```
samrima_preds = np.empty(len(test_series))
```

then when ready...

```
sarima_preds[t] = output[0]
```

Alternatively, change the dtype, to lower the precision e.g. fp32 if this is applicable.